# How to detect that my application's UI has moved to background?

Tags: android

Is there a universal way to be aware of application switching to background by either pressing "back", "home" or selecting one of other previously opened apps?

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current actvity's `onPause()` will be called. [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: Thanks! Should have refreshed my memory of `Activity`'s life cycle before asking, but the thought didn't even cross my mind :)